# How to define which layout to load first in android

Tags: android

I am developing my first android app. It has multiple layout files, how do I define which layout to open on the first time that the application is launched.

I currently have the code

```
setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

To change layout due to some activity but how do i make say the layout `signup` to be the one which opens everytime the app is loaded?

Comment: Probably, each Activity and each Fragment has its own layout file...

Comment: @DerGolem didn't get you. And yes each fragment has its own layout but i want one specific layout to be loaded everytime the user opens the app how is that managed?

Comment: You really don't want a `layout-swapper`. If so, the app is poorly designed. A good design implies 1 Activity - 1 layout, 1 Fragment, 1 layout. You assign each Activity its layout in the `onCreate()` method and to each Fragment in the `onCreateView()` method

Comment: @RickRoy you mean splash screen for the app ?

Comment: @Softcoder no I guess the app is poorly designed this is my first app and as Der Golem said i wanted to swap layouts. I have 2 layouts login and signup. I wanted to know how I could fix the signup.xml to be the default layout for whenever the app would open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Manifest file of your android project

[image]

**add this intent to that activity that you want first to be loaded**

```
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
```

**example**

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.YourPackageName.signup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
             // the below intent will let the application know your first activity to be
             // launched first

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you @Softcoder this is what I wanted. But is this a poor design? I don't understand why this will be a poor design but as I told earlier I am new to android so....

Comment: I think layout-swapper is another thing. but what you have asked and are doing is normal flow of android application like you asked what will be the first layout or activity that should be opened first.

Comment: Yes, that is all I had asked for and got a down vote too for asking that :D See I was for a moment really worried thinking all my hard work went down the drain coz this isn't the way to code in android. Why do ppl in here have to be so judgemental? I am just trying to learn..*sighs* thanks mate :)

Comment: Welcome .I think the person who downvote this question is due to the basic question you have asked. that happens to me also when i was a learning basic of android. Here people always wanted to have a question that is either NEW or A COMPLICATED ONE so no worry at all. bottom line = " YOUR PROBLEM SOLVED " :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new activity for the layout you want to show when app launches and add the following intent filter for this activity in the manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Note that only one activity in your app should have this intent filter - the one that you want to load when app launches.